# Create same model in multiple databases - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

As the title suggests, I am interested in how can I create the same model in multiple databases. I have the following scenario: every user has his own database (this is the simplified case) and when the user adds a new module to his app, I want to be able to create the db table for the module that he added. 
The idea that I currently have is to create dynamic models, add custom app_label, and than use a Database Router that creates the model in the corresponding database.

Is there an easier way to obtain this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have such a setup? Are you trying to do multi-tenancy? If so, there is an easier way; [`django-hosts`](https://github.com/jezdez/django-hosts) for example.

Comment: Hi! Yes, that is what I am trying to do. I use the isolated approach, and my problem is that I have some common models (e.g.: CustomUsers etc.) and I want to be able to give life to those models in separate databases.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the syncdb command - you can call it programmatically like so:

```
from django.core.management import call_command
call_command('syncdb')
```

In your case,  you'll want to use named arguments for any options you would have passed in at the command line:

```
call_command('syncdb', noinput=True, database=user_db)
```

Hope that helps.

Check this out also: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code

Comment: Thanks for the reponse TheBigC. Indeed, I took into consideration that option too, but my problem is how can I change the database in which the model will be added? It`s the same model, but according to the user that adds the module, it will be synced into different databases.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  The database argument to call_command would contain the name of the database (from settings.DATABASES) that you wish to add the model to - just like you would use --database with the syncdb command.

Comment: Yes, it contains the name of the database, but my problem was how to tell the model that I want it to be synced in one of the database from settings.DATABASES, at runtime.
I eventually managed to fix this problem going one level down and using sql_create_model and executing the raw SQL directly.

Comment: Using call_command (above) does exactly that - it allows you to, at runtime, call syncdb against the database (where you specify the database in the call to call_command.)  It happens at runtime, in your view, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the migrate command with different arguments. For instance if your db aliases are primary and secondary

do this

```
    python manage.py migrate --database=primary

    python manage.py migrate --databases=secondary
```